# Limit selector to specific anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with internal anchor tags that take the visitor to various div's on the page as well as jQuery tabbed content that also uses anchor tags. I am using ScrollMagic for smooth navigation between internal anchor tags but it also triggers on the jQuery tabbed content causing unwanted results. Is there a way to ignore certain internal anchor tags?

Here is the line of code that links ScrollMagic to internal anchor tags. How can I make it ignore a div with a certain class?

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the class to the `:not` selector:

```js
$('a[href*="#"]:not(.myclass, [href="#"])').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
    triggers
</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="myclass">
    doesn't trigger
</a>
```

Comment: I have noodled with this for an hour without success. Replacing my first line of code with yours causes everything to stop working - including the anchors without classes.

Comment: @LyleCrumbstorm your goal is to have the click handler ignore elements with a class right? Using the same code you have , `$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])')`, simply add the class name you want to ignore : `$('a[href*=#]:not([.CLASS_TO_IGNORE[href=#])')`. I hope that makes sense

Comment: I understand that but remain unsuccessful.

Comment: Moogs is correct. The selector should be `a[href*="#"]:not(.static-anchor, [href="#"]` not `a[href*="#"]:not(.static-anchor[href="#"])` like in the code of the question.